# Application Error when Quitting - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I quit my application, I get this error:

```
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Warning>: _CGSReferenceWindowByID: Window id 0xffffffff not found (locally or shared)
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Apr 11 20:32:31 imac.subnet192.com NetCalc[25082] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create window context delegate.
2012-04-11 20:32:31.679 NetCalc[25082:707] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x136f3, window:0xffffffff
```

The problem doesn't seem to be in the code, closing the application after launch (without touching anything) generates this error message anyway.

Update:

- The error only generates when I quit using the 'X' on the top right of the app. If I right click in the dock or if I use the tool bar to quit, no error is generated.
- I do not need to close the application to make the error appear. Closing the window suffices.
- I've unlinked all my outlets and actions, leaving only the default configurations. I still get the error.

Comment: Could you edit your question to incorporate the code for the textfields in question? (or at least explain how you set it up)

Comment: I commented out all of my methods and actions one by one, it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the behavior of the window. Checking the 'Release When Closed' checkbox of the window solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [Cubia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134234/674648) the checkbox 'Release When Closed' could solve the problem. If not uncheck the 'one shot' checkbox.